# On click is not working with two div nested in same row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, splunk

I have two HTML `div` nested in one `div class="row"`; the first one contains three `<button>`, the second one four `<p>`. Before adding the second `div`, the buttons included in the first `div` correctly worked if clicked; after having added the second `div` the button function `on.click` stopped working - button ID's were not changed, nor the js. If I remove the second `div id="stats"`, buttons turn up and running.

I guess there is a type conflict within the `row div` but so far couldn't find it.

```js
$('#btn-button-a').on("click", function() {
  console.log("click on button")
  var url = '....';

  window.open(url, '_blank');
});

$('#btn-button-b').on("click", function() {
  console.log("click on button")
  var url = '....';

  window.open(url, '_blank');
});

$('#btn-button-c').on("click", function() {
  console.log("click on button")
  var url = '....';

  window.open(url, '_blank');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<div class="row" style="margin-left:0px !important;">
  <div style="float:left; width: 184px; height: 152px; background: #bee0cc; border-radius: 8px; margin-left: 12px; margin-right: 12px;">
    <b>
        <label style="font-size: 18px; color: white; margin-top: 4px; text-align: center;">Title</label>
         <button id="btn-button-a" class="btn btn-primary-custom" style="width: 170px; height: 30px; font-size: 13px; padding-left: 0px !important; margin:6px; text-align: center">
          <span>Button a</span> </button>
         <button id="btn-button-b" class="btn btn-primary-custom" style="width: 170px; height: 30px; font-size: 13px; padding-left: 0px !important; margin:6px ; text-align: center">
          <span>Button b</span> </button>
         <button id="btn-button-c" class="btn btn-primary-custom" style="width: 170px; height: 30px; font-size: 13px; padding-left: 0px !important; margin:6px ; text-align: center">
          <span>Button c </span> </button>
        </b>
  </div>
  <div id="stats" style="float:left; width: 400px; height: 152px; background: #bee0cc; border-radius: 8px; margin-left: 12px; margin-right: 12px;">
    <label style="font-size: 18px; color: white; margin-top: 4px; text-align: center;">report</label>
    <p style="font-size: 13px; color: black; margin: 15px; text-align: left;">Frozen users: <b>$result_a$</b>
    </p>
    <p style="font-size: 13px; color: black; margin: 15px; text-align: left;">Frozen users %: <b>$result_b$</b>
    </p>
    <p class="status-inline" style="font-size: 13px; color: black; margin: 15px; text-align: left;">Status <b>$result_c$</b>
      <!--<span> </span> -->
    </p>
    <p style="font-size: 13px; color: black; margin: 15px; text-align: left;">t_number: <b>-</b>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

By removing from the second div `$result_a$`, `$result_b$`, `$result_c$`, which are tokens set by a Splunk search, the button work again.

Comment: Have you included all relevant code? Transferring your code to a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rg2snycd/ seems to work just fine, all buttons are clickable

Comment: I agree with @empiric , your code seems to be working fine for me as well.

Comment: For me as well.

Comment: Thanks you guys are right it seems to work on fiddle however is not working on the dev env I'm working on

Comment: Try press CTRL+F5 on your browser while you have your dev env opened...

Comment: @csbr any other css/js inlcuded on your page? Uploaded/ saved all relevant files?

Comment: @empiric It may be worth mentioning that $result_a$, $result_b$, $result_c$, in the div id="stats" are token getting populated by a query defined out of the HTML. I realized that if I remove the three tokens and leave text only the button work. Inspector / debug show that buttons "lose" the on.click() method, most likely after the tokens are populated.

Comment: @csbr how are those tokens poulated? Is any HTML replaced via an ajax call?

Comment: @empiric, tokens are set by a Splunk <search> in the <done> section

Comment: Is there an error in the console?

Comment: @KevinVandy no error from console

Comment: Do they work if you defer the click event handling up the DOM tree: `$( document ).on( "click", "'#btn-button-a",  function () {…}`? If so, your search may be replacing the DOM elements dynamically, thus losing the binding.

Comment: @ItoPizarro what you're saying I think is what is happening as debugging I notice that the on.("click") listener is correctly assigned while the js is being interpreted but is lost when the page is ready. I also tried to nest the listener in the following way 
`$( document ).ready()(function {
$( btn-button).on( "click", "'#btn-button-a", function () {…}});` but still not working